# Opengl, drawing a big square slows down the game

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I have been working on a game and encountered a really weird problem. Game renders at round 4k fps on my setup but after drawing a coloured square covering the whole screen + a little more as a background it drops down to 3k fps. Changing the size of the square to a smaller one makes the problem disappear.

Im drawing 40k triangles and particle systems already.

The square is a triangle strip loaded in a VBO.

```
GLfloat vBackground[4][3] = {
        { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },
        { 16.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f },

        { 0.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f },
        { 16.0f, 16.0f, 0.0f }
};
```

Im using the simplest shaders possible:

vertex
    #version 140

```
#extension GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location : enable

layout (location = 0) in vec4 vVertex;

uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
uniform vec4 inColor;

varying vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    color = inColor;
    gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vVertex;
}
```

fragment 
    #version 140

```
out vec4 vFragColor;

varying vec4 color;

void main(void) 
{
    vFragColor = color;
}
```

Is the pixel fill rate of the graphics card just too slow?

Comment: Does it have the same effect on all computers or just one?  What graphics card are you using?

Comment: If your framerate is being measured in kilo-FPS, then you're doing it wrong. Measure *time*, not FPS.

Comment: Im using HD6850, can try it on HD4850 but I dont have a Nvidia card to test it.

Comment: You should not measure your performance by FPS like this. (1 / 3000 seconds) - (1 / 4000 seconds) is just 83 microseconds, this is not a large difference at all. A change from 4k to 3k is not as large as from 40 to 30, *always measure time*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 thousand FPS means it takes you 0.25 **milli**seconds to render a frame. 3 thousand FPS means it takes you 0.33 **milli**seconds to render. A total difference of 0.08 **milli**seconds, or 80 **micro**seconds.

I wouldn't be worried about it. Your card isn't "too slow"; you're too sensitive to minor time differences.

Comment: Maybe i am a little too sensitive, it is just really surprising that drawing a square makes a lot bigger difference than 20k particles.

Comment: @hefty: How are you determining it's "a lot bigger difference"? What 20k particles?

Comment: What i meant is drawing 20k little squares pretty much doesn't affect the time that it takes for a frame to render, but drawing one big one does in a way that is noticeable. I was just curious why, hence the question.

Comment: @hefty: "drawing one big one does in a way that is noticeable" My point is that it's *not* noteworthy, because you're measuring time in a way that makes something that isn't noteworthy appear significant. You're looking at noise and believing that it is a signal.

Comment: @hefty: You're not answering the question, you've simply rephrased "a lot bigger difference" into "is noticeable". *What does 'noticeable' mean to you*? This is a lot bigger difference because ___. And where in your question are you measuring time? I only see FPS.

Comment: Any way i would measure that would tell me its 25%-30% of a difference and that has happened for the first time i have added any functionality. So how about the question now: whats causing it? Is it just how fast a gpu can fill the screen with pixels?